# How do I open an earlier version of python when the newer version is installed and the default?

Tags: python, linux

I have Python 2.7 and 2.4 installed on my computer (linux OS).

If I just type "python" as my command, the 2.7 version is opened. I have a script that I downloaded that is only compatible with python 2.4. How do I get python 2.4 to run instead of 2.7?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually Python is installed with both the version number in the executable and a default `python`; just use the versioned name:

```
python2.7
python2.4
```

Only the major and minor versions are part of the version name, not the micro version.